# Swift3: Call func data from main VC to TableVC for conditional cells

Tags: swift, swift3, tableview, viewcontroller

I'm trying to extend a function in my main View Controller (func `getCityWeatherData`) to the class below that only shows set items under certain conditions.

I've also marked sample data that has some criteria to be selected - how would I separate them from the usual array? I've tried what I read elsewhere, in the `numberOfRowsAt` section, but I'm confused.

```
class ProductRecsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

//Mark: Properties

var products = [Product]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if getCityWeatherData.humidity < 50 {
        return productsHumidity.count
    } else {
    return products.count
    } }
```

This is a sample cell I've created - I want the "weather: ..." but to define when the item shows.

```
guard let prod1 = Product(name: "XXX", photo: photo1, rating: 1, weather: "Humidity")
```

Comment: it's confusing, please explain the problem in detail again

Comment: @D4ttatraya I have data from a weather API in `ViewController`, but I also need to access it in `ProductRecsTableViewController`. How do I do that

Comment: @J.M. You should consider separating access to your weather API into its own Model object. If you put all the heavy lifting of actually accessing the API data in there, then you can do something like `let weatherApi = WeatherApi(), let currentWeather = weatherApi.getWeather()`. Your controller should be responsible for getting data from the model and giving it to the view. Many controllers may share a single model, though, and this would help you with your current issue of trying to reuse a function across two view controllers.

Comment: @JoshuaBreeden Thank you, I haven't heard about that yet. I'll have a look now. It seems like it'll lighten the load for me.

Comment: @J.M. If you're just getting started, I'd recommend Apple's free eBook "App Development with Swift" to you. It goes over not only the syntax of the Swift language, but some of the recommended design patterns that will help you logically lay out your app. This particular concept I'm talking about is called Model View Controller or MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to access a function called `getCityWeatherData` from your `ProductRecsTableViewController` class, which you can't do unless you have some type of relationship between the two controllers. You could make a protocol called `ProductRecsTableViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject` that has a single function that returns to your `ProductRecsTableViewController` the information you need. Either way, it sounds like you just need to pass data / information between two controllers either through delegation or properties.

UPDATE: #2

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController, CustomDelegate {
    func askForData() -> Data {
        return _whateverDataYouWant
    }
}

protocol CustomDelegate: AnyObject {
    func askForData() -> Data
}

class ProductRecsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var delegate: CustomDelegate?

    func myMethodThatNeedsAccessToData() {
        let data = delegate?.askForData()
        doStuffWith(data)
    }

}
```

at some point in this process you need to say `myProductsRectsTableViewController.delegate = self` inside your `ViewController`

Comment: I was reading about using delegation or protocols, but for some reason having a hard time understanding. I'll check with the `delegate: anyObject` you've given

Comment: Thank you, this helps explain the protocol process a bit more.